# How to create a hidden WiFi hotspot programmatically?

Tags: android, wifi

I want to create a hidden WiFi hotspot programmatically with an android device,but I can't find an answer with [developer.android.google.cn][1]

[1]: http:///https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration. just now I saw a  property named **hiddenSSID**, I tried to change it's value(true/false),but it did not work,could anybody help me?

```
 private void stratWifiAp(String mSSID, String mPasswd) {
    Method method1 = null;
    try {

        method1 = mWifiManager.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, boolean.class);
        WifiConfiguration netConfig = new WifiConfiguration();

        netConfig.SSID = mSSID;
        netConfig.preSharedKey = mPasswd;
        netConfig.hiddenSSID = true;
        netConfig.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);
        netConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
        netConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
        netConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(4);
        netConfig.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
        netConfig.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
        netConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
        netConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
        method1.invoke(mWifiManager, netConfig, true);

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your code to be something like this:

```
private void stratWifiAp(String mSSID, String mPasswd) {
    Method method1 = null;
    try {
        //通过反射机制打开热点
        method1 = mWifiManager.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, boolean.class);
        WifiConfiguration netConfig = new WifiConfiguration();

        netConfig.SSID = mSSID;
        netConfig.preSharedKey = mPasswd;
        netConfig.hiddenSSID = true;
        netConfig.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);
        netConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
        netConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
        netConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(4);
        netConfig.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
        netConfig.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
        netConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
        netConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
        method1.invoke(mWifiManager, netConfig, true);

        return netConfig;

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //return netConfig; or try to add here IF ONLY YOU ADDED THE ABOVE ONE!
}
```

Comment: I edited the answer you seems missing return statement. Add the following code `return netConfig;` around below your configuration code as long as it is still inside of try statement.

Comment: Yeah, but I state to return a void .

Comment: It is fine because the return statement is still inside the try statement. That is why I told you to put inside the try statement because your class has void state.